# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'z' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I am trying to execute this code,

```
def getInterPropreCat(h,cat):
    for txt in h:
        if txt['Categorie'] == cat:
            z=[txt['Max'],txt['Min']]
    g=getListZERO(h,cat)
    for text in g:
        z = getInterPropore(text['Min'],text['Max'],z[1],z[0])
        #   print(y)
    return z
```

and I do a test :

`print(getInterPropreCat(h,cat1))`
it's give me a result then I do a loop to get results of all categories :

```
for txt in CatList:
   getInterPropreCat(h,txt)
```

and I have this error :

```
z = getInterPropore(text['Min'],text['Max'],z[1],z[0])
```

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'z' referenced before assignment

any help ?

Comment: If no character in `h` has the matching `Categorie`, `z` never gets set.

Comment: you have to know that my funtion works it gives [3000.0, 1746.65] , that's good for me .. but when I use for txt in CatList: getInterPropreCat(h,txt) .. that gives a error

Comment: Provide a concrete example (along with a value for `CatList` and `h` for which `for txt in CatList: getInterPropreCat(h,txt)` raises that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you get the error because you didn't set any value at your first if statement  ,because the if statement requirement didn't matches, make sure that 'txt['Categorie'] == cat' returns True so that something being filled inside z list.

Comment: it return True .. and the code works with I call the function print(getInterPropreCat(h,cat1)).. but after using loop it gives that error

Comment: is z[0] and z[1] have values ? add something like print(z[0]) before executing 'getInterPropore'

Comment: its have values z=[txt['Max'],txt['Min']]

Comment: you have to know that its work it gives [3000.0, 1746.65] , that's good for me .. but  when  I use for txt in CatList:
   getInterPropreCat(h,txt)   ..  that gives a error